# La pantalla de mi tv se oscurece

Tags: javascript, html, css

Inicialmente digo que había hecho una pregunta similar, pero no tenia información que me envío el usuario recientemente.

Estoy haciendo un sitio web para unos smart Tv y pasado un rato las pantallas quedan completamente negras.

Aquí les dejo unas imágenes que me pase el cliente.

Así se pone al cierto tiempo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego de un rato mas queda así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí ven que no esta en modo de ahorro de energía

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Así se ve cuando carga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que no es por código pero igual aquí se los paso:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="content">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="google" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name=”robots” content=”noimageindex”>
<title>IQ para todos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(idVideo) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          playerVars : {
                listType:'playlist',
                list: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R-YLCFw2FYwptEqkZMRheFN',
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        player.setLoop(true);
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            currentIndex = event.target.getPlaylistIndex();
            playlist = event.target.getPlaylist();
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            if (currentIndex == (playlist.length - 1)) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
var inicio =true;
function startTime() {
  if(inicio) {
    inicio=false;
    realizaProceso();
  }
    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>a.m.</span>" : "<span>p.m.</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min  + " " + ap;
    var months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
    var days = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth+" "+curYear;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    //validarCambios();
    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);
}
setInterval("validarCambios();", 10000);
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
function validarCambios(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {
      if(response.estado['id']>$("body").data("id")) {
       // $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
        //realizaProceso();
        location.reload();
      }
    } 
  });
}
function realizaProceso(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {
      $("body").attr("data-year", response.estado['year']);
      $("body").attr("data-month", response.estado['month']);
      $("body").attr("data-day", response.estado['day']);
      $("body").attr("data-hour", response.estado['hour']);
      $("body").attr("data-minute", response.estado['minute']);
      $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
      $(".loader").hide();
      $(".carousel-congratulations").html(response.congratulations);
      $(".title-cumple").html(response.titleBirthday);
      $(".carousel-birthdays").html(response.birthdays);
      $(".title-events").html(response.titleEvent);
      $(".carousel-events").html(response.events);
      window.history.pushState("", "", '/iq/pru/');
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()" style="background: #154482;">
<div class="pantalla">
  <div class="mod-left fleft">
    <div class="video fleft">
      <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cumeve">
      <div class="cumple fleft">
        <div class="title-cumple" > <span class="fel">Feliz</span> Cumpleaños</div>
        <div class="cont-cumple">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-birthdays">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="events fleft">
        <div class="content-events" style="padding: 0;">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7100">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-events">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mod-right fleft">
    <div class="logo"><img src="admin/images/logo-iq.png" width="200" height="42" /></div>
    <div class="mt30">
      <div class="todos-t fleft">IQ para todos
        <div class="gal">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8350">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-congratulations">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_hour">
      <div class="fhour">
        <div id="clockdate">
          <div class="clockdate-wrapper">
            <div id="date"></div>
            <div id="clock"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" ></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
$hoy = getdate();
$day=$hoy['mday'];
$month=$hoy['mon'];
$year=$hoy['year'];
include_once "con.php";
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM multimedia WHERE id= ?;");
$sentencia->execute([1]);
$picture = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$titleBirthday = "";
$titleEvent = "";
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM binnacle ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
$sentencia->execute([1]);
$changes = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM congratulations WHERE state= ? ORDER BY id ASC;");
$sentencia->execute([1]);
$result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$estado ="active";
$contador=0;
foreach($result as $fila) {
    $congratulations .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'" style="background: transparent;">';
    $estado="";
    $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : "felicitaciones/homenajeado".$fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
    $col_title=$fila->title;
    $col_detail=$fila->detail;
    $congratulations .= "<div style='margin-left: 1em;' class='pruebaTmp'>";
    if (!( $col_title==="<!--empty-->"))
        $congratulations .= $col_title;
    if (!( $col_detail==="<!--empty-->"))
        $congratulations .= $col_detail;
    $congratulations .= '<img class="img-l" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" style="'.$fila->css.'"/>';
    $congratulations .= '</div>';
    $congratulations .= '</div>';
    $contador++;
}
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthdays WHERE day= ? AND month= ?;");
$sentencia->execute([$day, $month]);
$result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$birthdays = "";
$estado ="active";
$contador=0;
foreach($result as $fila) {
    $birthdays .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
    $estado="";
    $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : $fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
    $col_name=$fila->name;
    $col_surname=$fila->surname;
    $col_job=$fila->job;
    $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
    $birthdays .= "<div class='container container-happyBirthday'>";
        $birthdays .= "<table cellspacing='10' cellpadding='10'>";
            $birthdays .= "<tr>";
                $birthdays .= "<td>";
                    $birthdays .= '<img class="img_picture" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" />';
                $birthdays .= "</td>";
                $birthdays .= "<td>";
                    $birthdays .= '<h3 class="txt_name">'.$col_name.'</h3>';
                    $birthdays .= '<h4 class="txt_surname">'.$col_surname.'</h4>';
                    $birthdays .= '<h5 class="txt_job">'.$col_job."</h5>";
                    $birthdays .= '<h6 class="txt_date">'.$fila->day.' de '.$col_month.'</h6>';
                $birthdays .= "</td>";
            $birthdays .= "</tr>";
        $birthdays .= "</table>";
    $birthdays .= "</div>";
    $contador++;
}
$titleBirthday = ' <span class="fel">Feliz</span> Cumpleaños';
if($contador==0) {
    $suiche = 0;
    $titleBirthday = ' <span class="fel">Proximo</span> Cumpleaños';
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthdays ORDER BY month ASC, day ASC;");
    $sentencia->execute([1]);
    $result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $birthdays = "";
    $estado ="active";
    foreach($result as $fila) {
        if ($contador==0)  {
            if ($fila->month == $month)  {
                if($fila->day > $day) {
                    $contador ++;
                }
            } else {
                if($fila->month > $month) {
                    $contador ++;
                }
            }
            if($contador==1) {
                $col_image=($fila->image==NULL) ? "default.png" : $fila->id."/".$fila->image ;
                $col_name=$fila->name;
                $col_surname=$fila->surname;
                $col_job=$fila->job;
                $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 

                $birthdays .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
                $estado="";
                $birthdays .= "<div class='container container-happyBirthday'>";
                    $birthdays .= "<table cellspacing='10' cellpadding='10'>";
                        $birthdays .= "<tr>";
                            $birthdays .= "<td>";
                                $birthdays .= '<img class="img_picture" src="admin/images/'.$col_image.'" />';
                            $birthdays .= "</td>";
                            $birthdays .= "<td>";
                                $birthdays .= '<h3 class="txt_name">'.$col_name.'</h3>';
                                $birthdays .= '<h4 class="txt_surname">'.$col_surname.'</h4>';
                                $birthdays .= '<h5 class="txt_job">'.$col_job."</h5>";
                                $birthdays .= '<h6 class="txt_date">'.$fila->day.' de '.$col_month.'</h6>';
                            $birthdays .= "</td>";
                        $birthdays .= "</tr>";
                    $birthdays .= "</table>";
                $birthdays .= "</div>";
                $birthdays .= '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE year = ?");
$sentencia->execute([$year]);
$result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$estado ="active";
$contador=0;
foreach($result as $fila) {
    if( ( ($fila->month == $month) && ($fila->day >= $day) ) || ($fila->month > $month) ) {
        $col_name = $fila->name;
        $col_description = $fila->description;
        $col_city = $fila->city;
        $col_place = $fila->place;
        $col_day = $fila->day;
        $col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
        $col_month = ucwords(strtolower($col_month));
        $col_hour = strftime("%I", DateTime::createFromFormat('H', $fila->hour)->getTimestamp());
        $col_minute = strlen($fila->minute)==1 ? "0".$fila->minute : $fila->minute;
        $col_format = DateTime::createFromFormat("H", $fila->hour);
        $col_format = $col_format->format("a");
        $events .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
        $estado="";
        $events .= '<div class="title-events"> <span class="fel">Próximos </span>Eventos</div>';
            $events .= "<div class='container container-nextEvent'>";
                $events .= "<table cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3'>";
                    $events .= "<tr>";
                        $events .= "<td class='td_contentEvent'>";
                            $events .= '<h3>&nbsp;'.$col_name.'</h3>';
                            $events .= '<h5>&nbsp;Fecha: '.$col_day.'<small> '.$col_month.'</small></h5>';
                            $events .= '<p>&nbsp;Ciudad: '.$col_city.'</p>';
                            $events .= '<p>&nbsp;Lugar: '.$col_place.'</p>';
                            $events .= '<p>&nbsp;Hora: '.$col_hour.':'.$col_minute.' '.$col_format.'</p>';
                        $events .= "</td>";
                    $events .= "</tr>";
                $events .= "</table>";
            $events .= "</div>";
        $events .= '</div>';
        $contador++;
    }
}
$titleEvent = ' <span class="fel">Próximos</span> Eventos';
if($contador==0) {
    $sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM contents WHERE name = ? AND state = ?;");
    $sentencia->execute(["events", 1]);
    $result = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $estado ="active";
    foreach($result as $fila) { 
        $titleEvent = $fila->title;
        $col_content=$fila->content;
        $events .= '<div class="carousel-item '.$estado.'">';
        $estado="";
        $events .= '<div class="title-events"> <span class="fel">'.$titleEvent.'</div>';
        $events .= "<div class='container container-nextContent'>";
                $events .= "<table cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3'>";
                    $events .= "<tr>";
                        $events .= "<td class='td_dateContents'>";
                            $events .= '<h6 style="max-width: 29.6em;line-height: 1.8em;">'.$col_content.'</h6>';
                        $events .= "</td>";
                    $events .= "</tr>";
                $events .= "</table>";
            $events .= "</div>";
        $events .= '</div>';
    }
}
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$datos = array(
'estado' => $changes,
'wedewdwede' => $changes,
'congratulations' => $congratulations,
'birthdays' => $birthdays,
'events' => $events,
'titleBirthday' => $titleBirthday,
'titleEvent' => $titleEvent
);
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Main.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
html  {overflow: hidden;}
img {max-width: 100%;}
body {margin:0px; font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;color:#fff;}
.pantalla {height:100vh;width:100%;}
.fel{font-weight:200;}
.fl{font-weight:300;}
.fr{font-weight:400;}
.fsb{font-weight:600;}
.fb{font-weight:700;}
.mt30{margin-top:30px;}
.fleft{float:left;}
.txc{text-align:center;}
.mod-right{background:#154482;width:34%;height:100%;}
.mod-left{ height:100vh;width:66%;background:#ddd;}
.video iframe{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 66%;height: 59%;}
.cumeve{width:100%;height:41vh;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
.cumple{background:#1888c8;height:41vh;width:33%;}
.events{background:#ff25b0;height:41vh;width:33%;}
.logo{width:100%;text-align:right;padding:30px 30px 0 0;}
.title-cumple{background:#299fd8;font-size:25px;text-align:center;line-height:64px;}
.title-events{background:#e71a9d;font-size:25px;text-align:center;line-height:64px;}
.iq-todos{background:#ff25b0;margin-top:30px;}
.notas-t{font-size:30px;text-align:center;margin:150px 0 20px;}
.todos-t {font-size:30px;text-align: center;line-height:50px;width:100%; border-bottom:1px solid #50c1d8;border-top:1px solid #50c1d8;}
.flecha{background:#e71a9d;text-align:right;width:4%;}
.des-todos{font-size:20px;padding: 14px 10px;line-height:22px;width:52%;background:#ff25b0; height:91px;}
.desc{font-size:20px;padding:20px;line-height:25px;}
.gal{margin-top:0px;}
.item-t{text-align:center;padding:15px 0;font-size:25px;background:#1888c8;}
.link{color:#FC0;text-align:center;font-size:25px;}
.container-fluid {padding:0;}
.row{margin:0;}
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {padding:0;border:1px solid;}
.mod-der{background:#154482;height:100vh;}
.input-small{width: 150px !important;}
.sin-border{border-color: transparent !important;background:transparent !important;}
.fhour{position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:30px;}
#date{ font-size:20px !important;}
#clock{font-size:38px !important;margin-top:-8px;}
.mod-izq{background:#ddd;}
.video{ background:#09C;}
.container-happyBirthday {margin: 15px;}
.container-nextEvent {margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 0;padding-left: 2px;}
.container-nextContent {padding: 1em;}
.td_dateEvent {border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);}
.td_contentEvent {line-height: 15px;max-width: 325px;}
.carousel-item{}
.not-item{width:90%;background:#265ea9;height:auto;margin:0 auto;}
.cum-item {width:90%;height:90%;margin:0 auto;}
.img-cum{border:7px solid #fff;margin-top: 10px;}
.img-l{width:100%;}
.name{font-size:26px;margin-top:35px;margin-left:10px;line-height:25px;width:50%;}
.cargo{font-size:18px;margin-left:10px;margin-top:20px: line-height:25px;}
```

Gracias de ante mano a todo el que me pueda ayudar

Comment: Sera que se apaga automaticamente porque piensa que no tiene señal? mas alla del ahorro de energia, algunos solo se apagan.

Comment: @gbianchi Y eso como se podría solucionar?

Comment: Ni idea. Soko te comente algo q le pasa a mi tele comun.

Comment: Si la persona interactúa con la página también se apaga? Caso contrario, es posible que sea una especie de mecanismo de seguridad porque en algún tipo de paneles si los pixeles muestran la misma información mucho tiempo tienden a quemarse (por lo poco que entiendo del tema)

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal No, el usuario solo deja la pantalla de tvs moverse solo, http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/ esa es la URL, el sitio es para una clinica y esos tvs son internos como para que vean los proximos eventos, cumpleaños y otras cosas adicionales.

Comment: ¿Has probado a añadir una recarga cada X tiempo?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el sitio se recarga cada se agrega nuevo contenido desde el administrador ya que el sitio va y consulta la bitacora en la base de datos y hay algo nuevo se recarga

Comment: Las Tv tienen un timer para apagarse cuando no cambian de canal. Depende de la version del SO de la tv te permitirá modificarlo o deshabilitar el timer.